# MvvmCross Expensive Focus Changed Events

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, android-mvvm

In my MvvmCross project I currently perform recalculations after the user updates an editText by setting up a Focus Change binding.

```
local:MvxBind="Text URL; FocusChange LoadItemsFromServer"
```

However if the user presses the OK button, it doesn't trigger FocusChanged events, and the user ends up submitting before we have loaded the new items.

Is there an intended way to handle expensive operations for editTexts and ensure they are executed to completion outside of FocusChange events? How can I ensure the focus change event is executed to completion before the Button press gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure a method/function was finished before you click a button, you can disabled the command using can execute. First, you can watch this (Can execture start at minutes 26:00): [Episode 5: MVVM & Data Binding](https://youtu.be/GZDQptTQZsk).

If you don't want to watch the video, this is the step:

1. Create a variable to determine if the function is busy or not

   ```
   bool _is_busy
   public bool Is_Busy
   {
       get { return _is_busy; }
       set
       {
           _is_busy= value;

           OnPropertyChanged();

           SaveButtonCommand.ChangeCanExecute(); //this is the command you want to disable when it's busy or not
       }
   }
   ```
2. You add this to your command:

   ```
   public YourViewModel()
   {
         SaveButtonCommand = new Command(async () => await SaveButton(), () => !Is_Busy);
         //if your command not async, you can use this: 
         //SaveButtonCommand = new Command(SaveButton, () => !Is_Busy);
   }
   ```
3. Whenever you have a large function, you can just put this code at the beginning of the function:

   ```
    Is_Busy = true;
   ```

and make sure you set it to false when it's done.